# 8: How to specify multiple css media types in a libraries.yml file

Tags: media, theming, 8

Entering the list "screen, print" doesn't work:

```
base:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: { media: screen, print }
```

The resulting HTML should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen,print" />
```

Comment: Additionally the media attribute can contain any valid media query. Not sure if `screen, print` is valid, but `screen and print` would be right? Not sure if this is supported at all, but you could try `media: ['screen', 'print']` or maybe `media: "screen, print"`.

Comment: Ty @mradcliffe, the second one worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
css/styles.css: { media: "screen,print" }      # outputs media="screen,print" (WORKS!)
css/styles.css: { media: ['screen', 'print'] }  # outputs media="screen print"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with sass, you can also call other css files from your style.sass file, with a simple import:

```
// custom sass file for domo theme
@import "variables";
@import "front";
@import "formulario";
```

i had called many files from my library doing this:

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}

bootstrap-scripts:
  js:
    bootstrap/js/affix.js: {}
    bootstrap/js/alert.js: {}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  I edited my question to say: The resulting HTML should be:

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen,print" />